Polynomial-time quantum algorithms for lattice problems (GapSVP, SIVP, LWE)
The author of a recent preprint claims to have found polynomial-time quantum algorithms for solving the following lattice problems: the Decisional Shortest Vector Problem (GapSVP), the Shortest Independent Vector Problem (SIVP), and the Learning With Errors problem (LWE).
What is the plausibility of the correctness of such claim (are there proved obstructions to the claim? Are the used techniques known to fail the task? ...), and what would be the consequences for computational complexity theory is the claim is correct? (For example, what complexity classes would be proved to be equal?)

This question skirts close to "is this preprint correct?" (which is off-topic), but the more detailed follow-up questions ("are there proved obstructions?" etc) seem to me to help redeem it.

similar question, with a comment, from crypto.stackexchange: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/111385/polynomial-time-quantum-algorithms-for-lattice-problems

The claimed variant of SVP should be in $\mathsf{NP}\cap\mathsf{coNP}$ (any approximation factor larger than $\sqrt{n}$ is iirc), so there’s no real complexity theoretic consequence. Both factoring and DLOG are in this complexity class already.

This preprint has been critically evaluated by Omer Shmueli : The parameter choice needed for the algorithm is argued to be impossible. The existence of a quantum polynomial-time algorithm for the LWE problem (and other lattice problems), is prevented by the fact that there are not enough primes between 1 and log(n).

further feedback: http://www.chenyilei.net/ and https://nigelsmart.github.io/LWE.html


Update by Yilei Chen on April 18: Step 9 of
the algorithm contains a bug, which I don’t know how to fix. See the
updated version of eprint/2024/555 - Section 3.5.9 (Page 37) for
details. I sincerely thank Hongxun Wu and (independently) Thomas
Vidick for finding the bug today.
​    Now the claim of showing a polynomial time quantum algorithm for
solving LWE with polynomial modulus-noise ratios does not hold. I
leave the rest of the paper as it is (added a clarification of an
operation in Step 8) as a hope that ideas like Complex Gaussian and
windowed QFT may find other applications in quantum computation, or
tackle LWE in other ways.

